# how PreparedStatement.setString inside of the loop works?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a list of query parameter in my url that I want to use them in my java web service to run a query on a table

```
public Set<Result> getResult(String query, List<String> sortedQueryParamsValue) {
    Connection connection = getConnection();//jdbc connection
    //query is some thing like:  select * from table A where status = ? and Id = ? 
    try (PreparedStatement getStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {            
        for (int i = 0; i <sortedQueryParamKeys.size(); i++) {// sortedQueryParamsValue length is matching the number of values I need for the query and the order matches the order I am expecting
            String value = sortedQueryParamsValue.get(i);
            getStatement.setString(1, value);
        }
    try (ResultSet rs = getStatement.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            //add to the list of results
        }
    }
    //return the resultset

}
```

The reason that I used 1 always in `getStatement.setString(1, value);` is that I thought in each iteration one `?` is replaced with the value, but at the end I get some exception back saying java.sql.SQLException: IN or OUT param missing at position 2.

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong in here?

Comment: Change `getStatement.setString(1, value);` to `getStatement.setString(i+1, value);`

Comment: With your edit you invalidated your question, and made existing answers wrong. I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `1` every time in `getStatement.setString()`. You have to increment that number too in order to replace second `?` with an actual value.

Since you are only passing `1` all the time and then trying to execute the query, Java is saying that there is no value provided for the second `?` when you get `java.sql.SQLException: IN or OUT param missing at position 2`.

Replacing `getStatement.setString(1, value)` with `getStatement.setString(i+1, value)` should do the trick. But you'll have to ensure that the number of elements in `sortedQueryParamsValue` is equal to the number of `?` in your `getStatement` query.

EDIT: Corrected `setString(i,value)` to `setString(i+1,value)` after @Eritrean's comment.

Comment: Thanks @Meet K. but when I do what you said, the result came back empty.

Comment: Debug your program. Extract the query being generated at line `getStatement.executeQuery()` by adding a breakpoint. Then run this query manually on the database server and verify whether the query is correct or not, and whether it is actually returning any results.

Comment: yea it returns value. 
I couldn't find a way to see what is the query that getStatement.executeQuery() running.
I can only know what my query is and replace the ? with values and the ran it on my db and it returned value

Comment: Should be `setString(i+1, value)` since prepared statement indices start at 1 not 0

Comment: yeah , it does not return anyvalue

Comment: @WaterfrVilla Please accept the answer and close the question since your original issue has been solved. And learn how to debug your code, it will help you a lot. [This article](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) should help you get started.

Answer (score -3):

The problem was that passing query parameter through URL to the rest API can have some white spaces and those white spaces causes the query to return empty,
I am going to change 1 to i+1 just to not causing misleading readers

Comment: The problem was that you had `1` instead of `i+1`. White space has nothing to do with it, especially 'mostly white spaces'. And URLs and REST APIs have even less than nothing to do with it, as neither appears in your question.